# VSCode can't find header files when they are in different folders

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, linker, include, header-files

I have a problem with VSC. I started to use it recently and well I have 1 issue with it. My project has multiple folders, those folder just contain .h and .c files, but sometimes I need that .c file from one folder would read functions from .h file from another folder, and well when I include .h file, compiler can't find it. example bellow:
[image]

the only thing that works is by including full path to that file:
`#include "C:/Users/Name/Desktop/Project/Project_dir/components/configurations/I2C_master.h"`

Is this normal for VSC or I don't know how to use linker?

Comment: *"Is this normal for VSC or I don't know how to use linker?"* - Failure to find a header has absolutely *nothing* to do with linker configuration. This means your include path is not configured properly.

Comment: so linker doesn't link paths ?

Comment: Linkers link object code and libraries to make programs (or other libraries). They're post-compile. They have nothing to do with the pre-processor phase (which comes even before language compilation). Linker-based path specification is to tell the linker where to find *libraries* during the link-phase ; not headers during the pre-processor phase.

Comment: so is there a way to fix this error? Because I think this causes another problem in my code, when I get undefined reference to function, which is defined just in another folder.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem here is that you're writing the file path as if the two were located in the same directory.

If you are referencing a file from another directory you should write the relative path like this:

`#include "../configurations/I2C_master.h"`

Answer (score 1):

I am having that same problem. I have all of my headers in this folder called 'include' to have the interfaces separated of the source/implementation code. To compile in the makefile i added the flag `-Iinclude`, that searches for headers automatically to that folder.

The way I am including the headers is just the same as yours, `#include "header.h"`. I am getting the squiggles error, which is annoying, even tho the code compilation works just fine whit out problems.

Therefore it shouldn't be a problem with your code, but rather VS code that doesn't acknowledge it. The only solution that I can think of is to disable the squiggles for this kind of error, which is also not ideal I guess. Either way it's better then putting the specific path every time you need to include the header.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I am experiencing this issue as well, but primarily with cuda code.

I have my main.cpp file in project_folder/cpp, I have my process.cu file in project_folder/cuda, I have a common header process.h located in project_folder/include.

My Makefile has the include path and compiles fine.  I've added the include folder to c_cpp_properties.json

```
#include "process.h"
```

works great with intellisense in main.cpp and can use F12 to open

```
#include "process.h"
```

can't be found by intellisense in process.cu and doesn't respond to F12

```
#include "../include/process.h"
```

in process.cu works with intellisense

This is ok, but there are far more complicated include situations where it isn't desirable to put the full path when it is already in the provided include path in c_cpp_properties.json

VScode is suggesting the fix to add the directory to the include path (it even knows what path to add), but adding it doesn't remove the squiggles.